# How does server handle JSON in the body of a POST

Tags: json

I am using jQuery to post JSON data to a tomcat server and the server is handling the JSON array data perfectly!  It is as though I passed key=value request parameters along with the URL.

So why am I posting this?  I would like to know how the server treats JSON in the body of a request and how the data ends up being interpreted as request parameters.  I have Googled my a** off and all I find is how the server sends JSON back to the client.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't handle the JSON, the application deployed *inside* Tomcat does, and you've told us nothing about that.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to keep the two separated.  Before getting into my application muck, doesn't the server itself look at HTTP headers and content types in order to perform certain operations on the input stream PRIOR to my application seeing it?

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax() converts JSON data into key-value pairs (querystring style) by default.  You need to set `{ processData : false }` in the AJAX request to keep it as raw JSON.